# -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING in Websphere AS

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

I am migrating my Application from `Tomcat 7` to `WebSphere 8.5`

In `Tomcat 7` *i* Used

> -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false

to reslove Double Quote Issue while Compiling `JSP` page , i am searching for its eqvivalent parameter in `WebSphere`.

I Found a Web Container Custom Property

> com.ibm.wsspi.jsp.evalquotedandescapedexpression=true

for `WAS 8.5` but it is not working.

I get Following error:

```
JSPG0055E: Unable to create an xml attribute from name [] value [%]
```

Basically Error Occured in follwoing case

```
<html:input value="<%="abc"%>"></html:input>
```

now the Solution is

```
<html:input value='<%="abc"%>'></html:input>
```

but it is not possible in my case since there are so many JSPs,In Tomcat this Issue was Resolved by Adding following Property

> -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false

Comment: In Websphere, are you getting the same error with and without `evalquotedandescapedexpression` ?

Comment: yes i am getting same Error

Comment: Can you describe how did you set that property ?

Comment: IN Administrative console GOTO:  
WebSphere application servers > <Server Name> > Web container > Custom properties > New...

Comment: "but it is not possible in my case since there are so many JSPs" 

Can't You just create simple batch/bash script with regular expression in order to replace all occurences? Maybe it's a workaround, but as You said it's working solution.

Comment: it looks like that is the only option i have...:( thanks anyway.......

Comment: May `com.ibm.wsspi.jsp.enabledoublequotesdecoding` property help?  Documentation [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Frweb_custom_props.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have too many JSPs you can try the next conversion code. It covers many of the cases and after you can adjust those special cases:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JSPParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("([A-Za-z]+\\w?\\s*=\\s*(\")<%=\\s*[^%>]*\"+[^>]*\\s*%>(\")\\s*)");

        // Pass the input JSP in the first argument
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(args[0]);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
        String fileName = args[0];
        int n = fileName.lastIndexOf("/");

        // You must have a "was" subdirectory from the source location
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, n + 1) + "was/" + fileName.substring(n + 1);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                n = matcher.groupCount();
                for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                    line = line.substring(0, matcher.start(i)) + "'"
                            + line.substring(matcher.end(i));
                }
            }
            fos.write(line.getBytes());
            fos.write("\n".getBytes());
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        lnr.close();
    }
}
```